# how to open an iOS app from a mail link

Tags: ios

I have googled and also found the way it can be done i.e. using **URLSCHEME**. but when i implement the same it won't works for me . i don't know where i go wrong .

below is the changes i have done **info.plist** file

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>Sipapp</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.infy.prd.Sip</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

now after executing the app when i  write **Sipapp://** on safari it does not open the ap rather it shows " **There is no application set to open the URL sipapp://**"

Please help .

Comment: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: @iDev follow the same steps from there only but still getting th same error

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching for is Universal Links. Check this documentation for it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html). It's pretty simple and straight forward. And [here](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9) is a step by step explanation of how to support them. And afterwards, you can validate your own custom universal links [here](https://branch.io/resources/universal-links/) or [here](https://limitless-sierra-4673.herokuapp.com). Cheers!